# wrapper command for sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, scripting, configuration

Is there a command to set settings in `sshd_config`, instead of manually editing the file? I would prefer it to do this way, because it's easier to automate. Otherwise I'd have to `grep` config with my script.

Comment: Not a great idea. This has the potential for going horribly wrong. If you go that route, I hope you at least have your `/etc` files under version control. I recommend `etckeeper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no standard tool to change settings in `sshd_config`, Ubuntu's post-installation script has some functions for modifying the configuration.

It supports:

- enabling and disabling options
- renaming options
- reading the value of settings, e.g. it retrieves `22` from `Port 22`
- setting the value of settings, e.g. it can set `22` for `Port`: `Port 22`

There are limitations:

- it does not support contexts (like `Match`)
- it's not aware of the values a key expects, e.g. `AllowUsers user@host more@multiple values`

It can be found on http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/openssh/oneiric/view/head:/debian/openssh-server.postinst

An alternative to such functions using `sed`. For example, to change a Port setting:

```
sed "s/^ *Port .*/Port 22/i" -i sshd_config
```

Obviously, this only works if Port was defined before. As an alternative, you can remove existing settings and append the new setting:

```
sed "/^ *Port/di" -i sshd_config
echo Port 22 >> sshd_config
```

Answer (score 1):

As with approximately 99.9999999% of *nix config files, no.

Answer (score 1):

Most applications that provide separate wrappers to edit their config files do so to avoid dangerous [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#File_systems) (like the `visudo` command) or to avoid a syntax error from corrupting the application (again, like what `visudo` is there for). These things don't really apply to `ssh_config`.

So the short answer is **no**. However, that doesn't stop you from making your own.

Comment: There's no reason to turn off `sshd` while editing `sshd_config`! In fact, you would normally never turn off `sshd`, just restart it after changing the configuration. The main reason for `visudo` isn't race conditions (though that's a factor too), it's primarily there to avoid locking yourself out due to a syntax error that you would no longer be able to fix because `sudo` wouldn't be letting you do it.